# Sync (button) on Iphone Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, synchronize

Can anyone tell me How does the Sync Button on many Iphone app. works (like 'Le Monde').
The button download and replace all files of the application? only look for change (new entry) on the database and add them?....

Thanks,

Comment: You're going to have to provide more details. Specifically, what "sync button" are you talking about? Is this a custom button you've written, or are you talking about a possible future application? What do you currently have?

Comment: I'm talking about a future Application. I just want to know does it  work or how can it work. You can have a example in the application ('Le Monde').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a button like that is making a web service call, depending on the call you may be updating or replacing the information currently on the device.

Some web services will allow you to ask for information since a certain date:

```
/FetchArticles?afterDate=200911011952
```

Some will just provide you with a set amount of information.

Most of the time the calls to a web service will return light enough data that you can just replace what you had with what you fetch, but sometimes the data is a little heavier(images, video, etc...), so you'll want to hang onto what you already have and add to it.

Without knowing more about your App, or if it even uses network resources it's hard to provide any more help.

Comment: When people will download the application they will have to choose and download which modules do they want for the application.

 Module have webpages content, sounds and even pictures. After downloading the  module, they will have access to it inside the application, so no connection.

 The sync button will be on the homepage, it will search inside an external database for new entry in every module, if something as change or something new. It will even check if some part of the application are new and download files (newer version).

Comment: Sounds like you just want a pretty standard web service, google for "RESTful web services"